# EditText with scorll view

Tags: android, xml, android-design-library

i used scroll view  with a Linear layout and inside the linearlayout there us an Edit text when i pressed on it the keyboard hide it i solve it with change scroll view to linear layout but it is a must to make the allover view scrollable . the code is here

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mScrollView"
    tools:context="com.mostafa.android.riahana.calculateActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="backIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/item_calculate"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/ima1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/whitecircle"
                android:src="@drawable/pppp" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/ima2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/whitecircle"
                android:src="@drawable/pppp" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/ima3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/pic" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editPicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="getImageFromGalary"
            android:text="@string/selectYourPic"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/selectServices"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectservices"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/eyeleftprocess"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/DescriptionYourAge"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/myedittext"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this make your `ScrollView` **`android:fillViewport="true"`**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mScrollView"
     android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.mostafa.android.riahana.calculateActivity">
```

and Use **`android:windowSoftInputMode=""adjustPan"`** inside manifest file to your activity like this

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: @mostafazaghloul happy to help you

Comment: I have less than 15 repet

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

You can play around with this field and try other values to find the best in your situation.

Comment: Thanks  it work with this option android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"